# Can I plan ahead for Android app rollback without skipping version number?

Tags: android, version-control, apk

I've seen a couple postings on this site already about HOW to do a rollback. General consensus is to rebuild project in previous state with a higher version number and publish that as a "rollback." But that means if I want to plan for the worst-case scenario, every time I publish an app I need to generate another apk with a higher version number, meaning whenever I publish a new version the numbers will skip. Is there a way to do this without skipping version numbers?

Process I was thinking that involves version skipping:

- For this release I generate an apk with version 1.0.0 and one with version 1.3.0 and publish 1.0.0
- Next release I generate an apk with version 1.2.0 and one with version 1.5.0 and publish 1.2.0
- If things go so bad I need to revert, I can then publish 1.3.0 as rollback
- Then next release I generate an apk with version 1.4.0 and one with version 1.7.0 and publish 1.4.0
- If things go bad I can publish 1.5.0 as rollback
- (so on and so forth)

Comment: First, skipping version numbers doesn't really matter, so I'm not sure why you'd want to avoid it.  But you can always roll back to a previous version in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

it does not matter whatever you give as string to versionName.
Like if versionName are 1.0.0 then you updated to 1.1.0 (with versionCode 125 and 164).

If things go wrong for you in 1.1.0 and you want to revert back, then you can always revert to the 1.0.0 commit (assuming you use git, hg or any other VCS), and give a higher versionCode to versionName 1.0.0 (like 165) (PS. this new version 1.0.0 must have versionCode > 164, as 164 was already deployed on the Play Store before).